# Simple ruby program

Tags: ruby

just now I teach someone ruby and I need to give simple program (1-3 classes) to write. Could you give me an example of such program? Or some web resources? It should not be complicated it self, rather it should show ruby (is awesome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://ruby4kids.com/

Answer (score 1):

Chris Pine's [Learn to Program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/) is available online and uses Ruby as its language. It's geared towards novice programers and should contain easy examples. At the end of various chapters you'll also find sections called "A Few Things to Try", which contain nice exercise suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found http://rubykoans.com/, and its quite great :)